# Python 3.x How to access the element of the index before the index of element of my i in for loop?

Tags: indexing

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in a:

```
 list1.append(i)
 list1.append(i-2) `i-2` is not functioning why?
```

## Like for example, I am now in the index of element 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is not an index. It is the element present in the list itself. When you say you are now in the index of element 4, you are actually having element 4 not the index. So, you cannot treat like an index.

Python For loop is an interator based loop. It is used to step through items in lists, strings etc

The code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

list1 = []

for i in a:
    print(i)
    list1.append(i)
    list1.append(i-2)

print list1
```

will produce the below output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
[1, -1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
```